# Android Bundle vs Java plain object (POJO) - serialization/de-serialization performance

Tags: java, android, performance, serialization, deserialization

I am passing some data from an activity to other activity. I have 2 solutions as below:

1. Use Bundle

   ```
   Bundle args = new Bundle();

   args.put ("key1",  serializable_object1);
   args.put ("key2",  serializable_object2);
   args.put ("key3",  serializable_object3);

   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra ( "args", args );
   ```
2. Use Java plain object

   ```
   public class FragModel implements Serializable {

       public Serializable key1;
       public Serializable key2;
       public Serializable key3;
   }

   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
   FragModel model = new FragModel();

   model.key1 = serializable_object1;
   model.key2 = serializable_object2;
   model.key3 = serializable_object3;

   // ....
   intent.putExtra ( "args",  model );
   ```

My question is which solution is better for performance? better for serialization/de-serialization?

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Bundle** is the default communication and data transfer method provided by android platform. You can use serialize in android too but its not recommended. Try **Parceable** as an alternative to serialize.
This is taken from android [developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html):

> **Warning:** this interface limits how its implementing classes can change in the future. By implementing Serializable you expose your flexible in-memory implementation details as a rigid binary representation. Simple code changes--like renaming private fields--are not safe when the changed class is serializable.

As for performance, I can only say that serialize has worst performance. I dont know the difference in performance of Parceable and Bundle.